# Make odds and even rows in UIList with a different color? (Kind of 'Zebra' style)

Tags: scripting, interface, panel

I was wondering if this is possible to achieve (and if so, how):

[image]

(Notice the slighly more brilliant even rows)

Is just a `template_list` with an `UIList`